# 301 permanent redirect. (example.com) to (www.example.com) Magento

Tags: .htaccess, magento, redirect

I expect this to be a simple answer, yet it is a question I have been struggling to confirm after searching on Google and through similar questions.

I am wanting to make sure that my site has a 301 redirect in place to redirect my website URL (example.com) to (www.example.com). When I type in the browser my URL without (www.) in front of it, my page opens as (www.example.com) which is good, however how can I be certain that Google sees this as a redirect for SEO purposes?

I have not added any redirects to my site, so unless my version of Magento (1.7.2) has this redirect already set up or the theme I am using has this redirect set up, then it won't be set up.

I have read that I will have to redirect every page, not just the Home page. I am also aware of the URL Rewrite Management tool in the Magento backend, but I don't know whether I need to add rewrite there or whether I need to enter them into the sitemap.xml or .htaccess file so that Google knows I want my links redirected to the (www.example.com) URL.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be better direct using htaccess

```
# Redirect non-www to www:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

http://dense13.com/blog/2008/02/27/redirecting-non-www-to-www-with-htaccess/

Also,changed in url of secure and unsecure url of magento instance
to

```
 www.example.com  ,for please go to admin>system>configuration>General>Web>
```

Comment: Amit. Thanks for the answer, I have added that to my .htaccess file. I do not understand what you have said regarding the secure/unsecure? In the Magento backend I have already set the Unsecure as http://www.example.com and the secure as https://www.example.com. Is that what you are meaning?

Comment: if you makes secure and unsecure url to www.example.com,then,site default url www.example.com.it is good for seo and if any visitor come  with www.ex.. then it does not needed to 301 redirection.

Comment: Thanks Amit. However, I added the code above to my .htaccess file and everything continued to work on my Live server. But when I moved my Files and Database to my Local server (MAMP), it appears that this code has caused problems. When I try to access my Local site in my browser I get the error message "Safari can't find the server". The usual URL is localhost/examplesite/ however now the browser redirects it to www.localhost/examplesite/ (which is what the code is telling it to do). But even when I re install the old version that use to work, the error is still there. Do you know how to fix?